# drop down menu of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I think the code shouldn't got any errors since I compared it with video tutorial few times already. However, the dropdown menu still not function. It must be the error of file directory or path. Please help me out.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <title>Dropdowns</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dd-menu" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Dropdown</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Grid system</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Buttons and Icon</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Form control</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--latest compiled and minified javascript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">

   </body>
   </html>
```

This is the screenshot of my file path.[image]

my screen output got dropdown button but only can click with no function.
[image]

Comment: Why is the css link at the bottom? Put it in the `head`.

Comment: And the location of your jQuery should be `src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"`

Comment: thank you afaolek, you make my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the path of the script tag calling jquery.

For the example you have provided with the "js" folder in the same folder as the html document, the correct script tag is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Examples of using relative paths in an html document:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script> <!-- means "look one folder above this folder for the 'js' folder" -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> <!-- means "look for the 'js' folder inside this folder. -->
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script> <!-- means "look for the js folder in the server root". -->
```

Further reading:

- Setting up your [bootstrap template.](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)
- [Quick reminder about file paths](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

Comment: Thank you, now i got better understanding about file path.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery path is wrong:
Replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js". A leading " / " in the source attribute is referencing a folder relative to the root of the file system.